# How can I create text channels using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a command that creates a text channel. However, its not working. It doesn't even show an error. I am using Discord.py Rewrite.

Here is the code I've tried:

```py
@client.command()
async def addcha(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel):
   await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(channel=None)
   await ctx.send(f"A new channel called {channel} was made")
```

Answer (score 1):

> await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(**channel=None**)

`Guild.create_text_channel` doesn't have a `channel` kwarg, so not sure what you're trying to do here. Further, I don't think you can use a `converter` to cast your argument to a `TextChannel` that doesn't exist yet. You just have to pass in the name of the channel.

```py
@client.command()
async def addcha(ctx, channel_name):
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(channel_name)
    await ctx.send(f"A new channel called {channel_name} was made")
```

More info on what you can do when creating a `TextChannel` in the relevant [API Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel).